# SSRS How do you increase the size of the text report parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to pass an image into a report via the text report parameter.
However, it only seems to work when the image is small. The code I am using to call the report is along these lines:

```
    private CustomerAttachment LoadFromReportServer(byte[] imgAsByte)
    {
    string mimeType, encoding, extension;
    string[] streamids;
    Warning[] warnings;

    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgAsByte);
    _reportParams = new List<ReportParameter>();
    _reportParams.Add(new ReportParameter("p_farm_map", base64String));

    var rptViewer = new ReportViewer();

    rptViewer.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
    rptViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
    rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

    _reportServerUrl = "http://MyReportServer.wesenergy.local/ReportServer";
    _reportFolderPath = "/WcfReportTest/";
    _reportName = "FarmMapReport";

    rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(_reportServerUrl);
    rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = _reportFolderPath + _reportName;
    rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(_reportParams);

    //Fails on this line here
    byte[] bytes = rptViewer.ServerReport.Render(_reportFormat, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

    return new CustomerAttachment(_customerId, _fileName,"application/pdf", bytes);
    }
```

In the report `p_farm_map` is a Text report parameter. 
The error I get on larger files is `rsInvalidParameter` error.

Is there a way to explicitly set the max size of the Text data type?

Comment: How big are the sizes of the files names? Is it the complete path? I know windows has a hard limit of like 255 or something which I have run into before

Comment: The file size is around 700kb. When I call the report the image has already been converted from a stream to byte[] to a base64String. This code works for smaller files so I suspect the issue is around the SRSS Text data type.

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of a response to this question and project time constraints the alternate solution was to save the image to a share; pass the file location through via the text field to the report and have the image use that text value as the source for the image. Not an ideal solution as I have to write and read from a disk (slow). Plus I now have to clean up these  files as well.